# Jquery not removing row

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery where it append a row with link to remove the row. I have this code but it doesn't remove the row.

everything is working except for the function `remove()`

There is no error too.

```
var currentTotal = 0;

function remove(id) {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();

}

$(document).ready(function() {

      var arr = [];

      $("#btnAdd").click(function() {

        var medname = $("#MedicineID option:selected").text();
        var id = $("#MedicineID option:selected").val();
        var qty = $("#myID").val();

        $.ajax({

          url: '/Purchases/GetValue',
          type: 'GET',
          datatype: 'json',
          data: {
            'id': id
          },
          success: function(val) {

            if (qty == 0) {
              alert("Please define the quantity");
            } else {
              var item = $('#MedicineID').val();

              if ($.inArray(item, arr) != -1) {
                alert("Specified medicine is already been added")
              } else {
                arr.push(item);
                if (currentTotal == 0) {
                  currentTotal = val * qty;
                  $("#tblList").append('<tr> <td>' + medname + '</td>  <td>' + qty + '</td><td> ' + val + '  </td>  <td><a onclick="remove(' + id + ')" class="remove" href="#">Remove</a></td></tr>');
                  $('#total').text(currentTotal);
                } else {
                  var price = val * qty;
                  currenTotal = currentTotal += price;
                  $("#tblList").append('<tr> <td>' + medname + '</td>  <td>' + qty + '</td><td> ' + price + '  </td>  <td><a onclick="remove(' + id + ')" class="remove" href="#">Remove</a></td></tr>');
                  $('#total').text(currentTotal);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        })
      });
```

Here is the tables in my view

```
 <table id="tblList" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Item
            </th>
            <th>
                Qty
            </th>
            <th>
                Price
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th></th>
            <th><p id="total">0</p></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You have loads of errors in your code for sure. Please try to create a [mcve] and show us the issue.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Everything works except the `remove()`. I just want to show how i append my tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just calling the function with id and try to remove the id.
 But what you have to do is pass the element while you are calling the function.

```
function remove(id,element) {
      $(element).closest('tr').remove();
    }//try something like this
```

And in onclick function you have to edit code like this

```
onclick="remove(' + id + ',this)"
```

Finally your code should look like this [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/sameeraliyanage/j47y2e1a/1/)

Comment: Before I downvote you, write answer with explanations.

Comment: @wafuqu What did you do to make it work and why didn't it work in the first time? Just curious.

Comment: I think its because i didn't say to add "this" to onclick element when i posted the answer first time.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I was referring to his first answer

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to try this hope its works.

```
     $(".remove").on('click', function (e) { 
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the remove function to capture the event

```
   function remove(id,event) {
      $(event.target).closest('tr').remove();
    }
```

When you call use the below code

```
$("#tblList").append('<tr> <td>' + medname + '</td>  <td>' + qty + '</td><td> ' + price + '  </td>  <td><a onclick="remove(' + id + ',event)" class="remove" href="#">Remove</a></td></tr>');
```